# Python flask webservice can be reached when on LAN, not on WLAN

Tags: python

So I'm running a simple (python) flask web service on the Raspberry Pi

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    timeString = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    templateData = {
        'title': 'Welcome to Dante\'s home automation!',
        'time': timeString
    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

def runApp():
    app.run(debug=flaskdebug, use_reloader=False, port=flaskport, host='0.0.0.0')
```

For test purposes I just let generate a simple message for now (flaskport = 5003).

So when I connect the Raspberry Pi via cable on LAN, I use the `ifconfig` command in the terminal to double-check what the IP is that is been given in the network.

And from here I can use any computer or device (e.g. my phone) to sent a command to the Raspberry Pi via the flask server.

On the Raspberry Pi itself I can also use a browser to reach the flask web service.

So up till here, everything works fine.

At this point, I wanted to try to do the same thing, only now I wanted the Raspberry Pi to be connected via its Wi-Fi and not the LAN cable.

I can only reach the flask server on the local Raspberry Pi itself in a browser.

But for some reason, I just can not see or find the Raspberry Pi anymore from any other device in the network.

My first thought was it could be some setting on the Raspberry Pi like a firewall thing or something that kicks in when on Wi-Fi, but I could not find any setting related to this (maybe I am looking in the wrong places).

Any thoughts what this can be or how to fix?

Comment: You have described your challenge pretty well, but you left out the facts like what IP and what Wi-Fi AP you use and did you try to ping the Raspberry Pi via the Wi-Fi connection?

And please use a capital i for I!

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean with the ip and Wi-Fi AP, but what I did: Connect the pi with my local available home Wi-Fi via the on-board wifi, and have all the other things like IP be auto assigned. When starting a browser on the pi, I can connect to a website. But for example on my phone (on same Wi-Fi as Pi) I can't fing the Pi via a scan app like Fing. Fun fact here as well is when I use the Lan on the Pi, it becomes visible again in the network. Something in the Wi-Fi seems to be mocking with it.